# MultiIndex DataFrame to a Standard index DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I convert a MultiIndex DataFrame to a Standard index DF?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'old_code': ['00000001', '00000002', '00000003', '00000004'],
'Desc': ['99999991', '99999992 or 99999922', 'Use 99999993 or 99999933', '99999994']},
)
df1.set_index('old_code', inplace=True)
df2=df1["Desc"].str.extractall(r"(?P<new_code>\d{7,9})")
print(df2.head(10))
```

My output looks like this

```
old_code match  new_code        
00000001 0      99999991
00000002 0      99999992
         1      99999922
00000003 0      99999993
         1      99999933
00000004 0      99999994
```

I'm trying to get it in a format like this?

```
old_code   new_code        
00000001   99999991
00000002   99999992
00000002   99999922
00000003   99999993
00000002   99999933
00000004   99999994
```

Comment: `df2.droplevel(1).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the second level index and then reset the index:

```py
print(df2.droplevel(1).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   old_code  new_code
0  00000001  99999991
1  00000002  99999992
2  00000002  99999922
3  00000003  99999993
4  00000003  99999933
5  00000004  99999994
```